# Why UDP header has 'length field'?

Tags: networking, udp, protocols

I couldn't understand why UDP header has 'length' field, and why it is needed?

If the reason is to know where the 'application message(L5 data)' begins in the segment, it can just be gotten from 'UDP data - UDP header length(it is already known value)'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does UDP have the field "UDP Length" twice in its packet?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182362/why-does-udp-have-the-field-udp-length-twice-in-its-packet)

Comment: @Steffen it's different from my question's point

Comment: I don't see how this is different since the other questions asks why there is a length field in the IP header and in the UDP header too which in my opinion is the same as you ask, only in different words. If you feel this is not a duplicate please describe what is different in your question.

Answer (score 8):

Because UDP can be transmitted over another protocol than IP.

And also because UDP transmits datagram messages with a length (udp length) which can be sent over multiple IP fragmented packets.
[image]

Source: https://notes.shichao.io/tcpv1/ch10/

Comment: IP packet fragmentation and reassembly happens at layer-3 (IP), and it is transparent to layer-4 (UDP). UDP will never know if IP packets are fragmented since IP will reassemble the packet fragments before passing the packet payload up to UDP.

Comment: It's helpful when you manage your own protocol over UDP over (fragmented) IP and you are receiving separated IPv4 datagrams and need to reassemble it yourself.

Comment: IP handles packet fragmentation and reassembly. A protocol inside UDP is twice removed from that. UDP itself never knows about fragmentation, and a protocol inside UDP will never know what UDP doesn't know. UDP will receive a full datagram, regardless of IP fragmentation, which has nothing to do with protocols at layer-4 or above.

Comment: True at high level programmation, but at low level programmation in practice it's helpful for buffer size allocation, for example when the IP layer wants to return a UDP datagram to the UDP layer.

Comment: It's useful when creating your own protocol and receiving IP datagrams. Useful, but ok not absolutely necessary…

Answer (score 6):

The UDP header length field is the length of the UDP header plus the UDP data. It is indeed redundant since this length can be calculated from the IP header total length field where the UDP datagram length is the IP total length minus the IP header length.

Comment: so why we need it?

Comment: Obviously a length field is needed to specify the amount of payload bytes. The fact that the protocol is embedded inside another protocol (IP) that also has length information about it's payload - which can be used to calculate the UDP payload length - makes the UDP length redundant. If however you would use the UDP protocol inside another (non-IP) protocol that does not have this information, you would need a UDP length field. So, as a standalone protocol definition without a requirement that it must always be embedded inside another protocol that contains length information, it is needed.

Comment: ip header length is in multiple of 4 bytes and udp header length in multiple of one byte

Answer (score -1):

UDP uses message stream NON FIFO as communication model between the sender and receiver. If the size is not mentioned then it will not be possible to decipher the message at rxr.
Say m1m2m3 is sent then each message to be notified so that u can trace back the message.
Regards