# Difference between struct ip and struct iphdr

Tags: c, networking, ip, icmp

I am trying to understand how the network is working, i'm doing some test, sending some package... anyway

My point is that i can't find the real difference between `"protocol" structure` and `"protocol header" structure`.

For the ip structure, they both sized 20 bytes.
but for exemple:

- `struct ip` and `struct iphdr` sized 20 bytes
- `struct icmp` sized 28 bytes
- `struct icmphdr` sized 8 bytes

I'm guessing that the `struct icmp` include a `struct ip/iphdr?` ?

And there is the same kind of structure with every protocol i have seen.
`struct udp` / `struct udphdr`,

Is it link to `IP_HDRINCL` set on with `setsockopt()` ?

So my question is What is the real difference between them ? And When use the good one.

**ip and iphdr** struct:

```
struct iphdr {
    #if defined(__LITTLE_ENDIAN_BITFIELD)
        __u8    ihl:4,
                version:4;
    #elif defined (__BIG_ENDIAN_BITFIELD)
        __u8    version:4,
                ihl:4;
    #else
        #error  "Please fix <asm/byteorder.h>"
    #endif
         __u8   tos;
         __u16  tot_len;
         __u16  id;
         __u16  frag_off;
         __u8   ttl;
         __u8   protocol;
         __u16  check;
         __u32  saddr;
         __u32  daddr;
         /*The options start here. */
};
```

And **IP HDR**

```
struct ip {
#if BYTE_ORDER == LITTLE_ENDIAN 
    u_char  ip_hl:4,        /* header length */
        ip_v:4;         /* version */
#endif
#if BYTE_ORDER == BIG_ENDIAN 
    u_char  ip_v:4,         /* version */
        ip_hl:4;        /* header length */
#endif
    u_char  ip_tos;         /* type of service */
    short   ip_len;         /* total length */
    u_short ip_id;          /* identification */
    short   ip_off;         /* fragment offset field */
#define IP_DF 0x4000            /* dont fragment flag */
#define IP_MF 0x2000            /* more fragments flag */
    u_char  ip_ttl;         /* time to live */
    u_char  ip_p;           /* protocol */
    u_short ip_sum;         /* checksum */
    struct  in_addr ip_src,ip_dst;  /* source and dest address */
};
```

ICMP structure code here : https://www.cymru.com/Documents/ip_icmp.h

Comment: Why are not the 2 codes using the same type names?  Note that bit-field types other than `_Bool, int, signed int, unsigned int`, like the above, is implementation defined behavior.

Comment: chux, i didn't create the structure, they're both defined in netinet/ip.h,

Comment: The _minimum IPv4 header size is 20 octets, but options can make that larger. ICMP is a protocol that is encapsulated as the payload of IP, and its header is not the IP header.

Comment: IP *pseudo header* google is your friend.

Comment: @wildplasser  Thank ! i didn't know that !

Comment: Really?  Google is *everybody's* friend!

Comment: And if i asked on SO, is because i didn't find on google, AND SO... @wildplasser

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/359045/what-is-the-significance-of-pseudo-header-used-in-udp-tcp (or read Comer)

Comment: @wildplasser i know how to use google.. so when you said "pseudo header" i found it ! i just never saw "pseudo header" in my search

Comment: The situation now seems to be a little different.When I opened the /usr/include/netinet/ip.h file in centos 7, I found that the definitions of struct iphdr and struct ip exist in the file at the same time.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`struct ip` and `struct iphdr` are two different definitions of the same underlying structure, brought in from different places.

`struct ip` is defined in `<netinet/ip.h>`, which is a reasonably standard header on UNIX systems.

`struct iphdr` is defined in `<linux/ip.h>`. This header (and structure) are Linux-specific, and will not be present in other operating systems.

If you're not sure which one to use, use `struct ip`; code which uses this structure is more likely to be portable to non-Linux systems.

---

`struct icmp` and `struct icmphdr` are a messier situation:

- `<netinet/icmp.h>` defines **both** `struct icmp` and `struct icmphdr`.
- `<linux/icmp.h>` also defines `struct icmphdr`, with a similar structure (but, as usual, different field names) as the definition from `<netinet/icmp.h>`.

First: Don't include `<linux/icmp.h>` unless you have a very good reason. You *cannot* include both headers -- they will conflict -- and most software will expect the netinet definition.

Second: `struct icmphdr` is, as the name implies, the header. `struct icmp` defines the contents of a structured ICMP message, like a destination unreachable message.

Comment: Thank you ! So what about `icmp` / `icmphdr` ?

Comment: Plus 1 for the portability advice of `struct ip` outside of Linux systems.